# how to add Image in Grid View header after header text

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying add  an  filter image  in grid view header  after header text in same column.  I tried adding image to header but it only shows  image  but not the text along with it.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<img src='.../...' alt='my image' />">
....
</TemplateField>
```

Can anybody suggest me the way to do it

Answer (score 4):

Just do something like this - note the `HtmlEncode=false`:

```
<asp:BoundField HtmlEncode="false" 
 HeaderText='<img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8c9778a09696aac804ed44f4c8033458?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" />Filter' />
```

It will render an image on the header and the word `Filter` next to it.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this...

```
<asp:TemplateField>
<HeaderTemplate>Some Header <img src=".../image.png" /></HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>Your Item</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```